# How to fetch keywords inside a Keyword in anguilla

Tags: cme, rtf

There are two dropdowns for my customization. One of which gets populated with 1 st level Keywords (K1, K2, K3) -(ie if "C" is the cateogory , I have K1 , K2, K3 . These are abstract Keywords. Under K1 I have A1,A2,A3 normal Keywords. K2 has B1,B2,B3 . K3 has C3,C4,C5 ).
The second dropdown gets populated based on the selection of First dropdown. If I select K1 then 2nd dropdown has A1,A2,A3. I am currently achieving this by doing the following -

1. Dropdown 1 loads when I load the category list (var list =
   category.getListKeywords();) [K1, K2, K3 ]
2. For dropdown 2 ,for instance dropdown 1 value is K1, I pass the keyword object of K1 and get the using items.  var list = keywordObj.getListUsingItems(new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter(), false, false);

**The second dropdown doesn't load if the user does not have permission to the publication where I have created the cateogory "C". It says no permission to read item tcm:xy-abc-def".**

**The getListUsingItems returns A1,A2,A3 Keywords tcmids but they are not from the context publication.**

**I can re-form the keyword tcm id by using the context publication Id. But I wanted to know if there is any other way to get the child-keywords inside an abstract Keyword.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the list of Keywords inside a Keyword as below -

1. var list = keywordObj.getList(new
   Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter(), false, false);
2. var listXmlDoc = list.getXmlDocument();
3. var keywords = $xml.selectNodes(listXmlDoc,
   "/tcm:ListKeywords/tcm:Item");
4. You can define the filter.
5. Load the list (Add event handler).

The "keywords" looks like this -

```
<tcm:ListKeywords xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
<tcm:Item xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ID="tcm:402-115887-1024" Title="K1" Icon="T1024L0P0" Type="1024" FromPub="010 Global Schemas" IsNew="false" Modified="2016-03-15T04:03:38" Key="K1" IsAbstract="false" Managed="0"/>
<tcm:Item xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ID="tcm:402-115888-1024" Title="K2" Icon="T1024L0P0" Type="1024" FromPub="010 Global Schemas" IsNew="false" Modified="2016-03-11T03:05:34" Key="K2" IsAbstract="false" Managed="0"/>
<tcm:Item xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ID="tcm:402-115889-1024" Title="K3" Icon="T1024L0P0" Type="1024" FromPub="010 Global Schemas" IsNew="false" Modified="2016-03-11T03:06:22" Key="K3" IsAbstract="false" Managed="0"/>
</tcm:ListKeywords>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tom.NET

```
var list = keyword.GetChildKeywords()
```

in CoreService

```
var list = client.GetList(keyword.Id, new ChildKeywordsFilterData());
```

I suppose in cme it should be something like

```
var list = keywordObj.getListChildKeywords(...)
```

Comment: In the anguilla documentation , I didnt see any method like this for a Keyword. And this doesnt work. Hence I went for getListUsingItems :(

Comment: TypeError: keywordObj.getListChildKeywords is not a function @Stanislav Maryenko